# Convert Arabic text to UTF8 in Android

Tags: java, android, utf-8, character-encoding, arabic

I am receiving data from JSON in arabic using UTF8 encoding

**"\u0639\u0644\u0649"**

when displaying it in textview its converted to "علي"

How I can get UTF8 back from this arabic text, assuming that I get arabic text input from keyboard

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question but have you tried `textView.setText("\u0639\u0644\u0649")` without any conversion? Looks like what you have got is already suitable to be displayed as it is.

Comment: The OP probably is unhappy that his debugger Watch window shows the Unicode string escaped, as opposed to as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are always in Unicode, only byte arrays have an encoding.

Your initial statement makes little sense. You are taking a String that contains three Arabic characters and converting it to a byte array in the default encoding, then converting these bytes back to a String assuming UTF-8 encoding.

```
scala> val str = "\u0639\u0644\u0649"
str: java.lang.String = ???

scala> str.length
res0: Int = 3
```

I see no benefits in this over `string = "\u0639\u0644\u0649"`. If you need the bytes that represent this string in UTF-8 encoding, you can call  `string.getBytes("UTF-8")`, but it's more likely that your communications library will take a string and let you specify the encoding somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine except that you have to `Encode` and and `Decode` your data into `Base64`. This worked for me. I can share the code if you need it.